# Accessing YUI RichTextEditor node

Tags: yui, rte

I'm inserting images to editor with id param. after that i'm trying to access it with Dom.get('id'), but it returns null.

I understand that it returns null because it works under parent window's scope. Is there any standard way to access it?

Answer (score 0):

For specialized YUI-related questions, and especially if you don't get the answer you're looking for on StackOverflow, you may want to post to http://yuilibrary.com/forum -- the YUI devs and many YUI specialists spend time there, and that's typically the best place to get YUI-related help.